# Problema com função recursiva, 2 parâmetros

Tags: c, funções, recursão

Estou tentando escrever este código usando recursividade:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

  int potencia(int i, int j)
  {
    return (j > 0) ? 1 : (potencia(i , j)i * j - 1) * i;
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int valor1;
    int valor2;

    printf("Insira um valor: ");    scanf("%i", &valor1);
    printf("Insira outro valor: "); scanf("%i", &valor2);

    printf("Resultado da potencia: ", potencia(valor1, valor2));

    return 0;
  }
```

Porém um erro me é exibido

```
F:\Atividade 47.c|7|error: expected ')' before 'i'|
```

Já alterei tudo possível e até agora nada deu certo, alguém pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 2):

Vou por aqui algumas coisas que estão acontecendo com seu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

  int potencia(int i, int j)
  {
    return (j > 0) ? 1 : (potencia(i , j)i * j - 1) * i;
    // ----------------------------------^
    //                                    \__ O Maniero falou desse operador aqui
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int valor1;
    int valor2;

    printf("Insira um valor: ");    scanf("%i", &valor1);
    printf("Insira outro valor: "); scanf("%i", &valor2);

    printf("Resultado da potencia: ", potencia(valor1, valor2));
    // ---------------------------^
    //                             \__ faltou o indicador de formatação de inteiro; o que vem aqui?

    return 0;
  }
```

Aproveitando, sua fórmula recursiva está exatamente assim:

```
                 / j > 0: 1
potência(i, j) ={
                 \ j <= 0: potência(i, j) i * j-1
```

Se formos tentar achar o valor de `potência(5, 1)`, qual seria o resultado esperado? Se seguirmos a lógica da sua fórmula, como `j > 0`, o resultado seria `1`. Isso está certo?

Se pegarmos a fórmula e tentar calcular para `potência(5, 0)`? Vou fazer o primeiro passo da iteração:

```
potência(5, 0) ==> potência(5, 0) 5 * 0-1
```

Essa recursão está certa? Ela irá convergir para algum valor eventualmente?

Answer (score 1):

```
(potencia(i , j) <qual operador vai aqui?> i * j - 1)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/Operator.c).

Você não pode ter dois operandos sem um operador. Falta colocar o que precisa ser feito com a potência de e e j relacionado ao i. Colocando um operador aí funcionará.

Answer (score -2):

The full solution in C#

```
using System;
class Power{
  static void Main(string[] args){
    long number1, number2, result;
    Console.Write("Type the BASE number: ");
    number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Define its EXPONENT: ");
    number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    result = power(number1, number2);
    Console.WriteLine("SOLUTION: {0} ^ {1} = {2}", number1, number2, result);
  }
  static long power(long n1, long n2){
    if(n2 == 0){
      return 1;
    }
    return n1 * power(n1, n2 - 1);
  }
}
```